# SQL Server Temp Table Insert from other temp table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

TmpTable1

```
Col1 = Category1
Col1 = Category2
```

TmpTable2

```
30 records for a month
```

How i can show 30 records for each Category so result will show 60 records

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `cross join` :

```
select t1.*, t2.category
from table1 t1 cross join 
       (select distinct category from table2) t2;
```

However if you don't have duplicate then you can directly express it as :

```
select *
from table1 t1 cross join 
      table2 t2;
```

Comment: Not sure how a cross join is going to return 30 rows per month.

Comment: @SeanLange. . . `30 records for each Category so result will show 60 records`

Comment: I see your interpretation now. Hard to say what they really want it is so vague.